# Test of Hypothesis for normal distribution for measurements with standard deviation (Edited-2)

Tags: chi-squared-test, normality-assumption, measurement-error

I am trying to revise a solved problem from John R. Taylor's "An Introduction to Error Analysis", Chapter 12, page 261 on chi-squared test. The problem definition is to find $\chi^2$ for a set of data given below and to validate the hypothesis that the distribution is normal.

Measured values of $x$ (cm)

731, 772, 771, 681, 722, 688, 653, 757, 733, 742, 739, 780, 709, 676, 760, 748, 672, 687, 766, 645, 678, 748, 689, 810, 805, 778, 764, 753, 709, 675, 698, 770, 754, 830, 725, 710, 738, 638, 787, 712

The calculated $\chi^2$ by the author is 1.80, and that since $\chi^2$ < number of terms in sum, so the hypothesis that the measurements are distributed normally is correct. Sum is defined by 
\begin{equation}
\chi^2= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(O_{k}-E_{k})^2}{E_{k}}
\end{equation}
where $k$ is the \textit{bin} number, $O_{k}$ is the number of observations and $E_{k}$ is the expected number.

Now, I wish to revise the same problem when all the data sets are associated with measurement uncertainties (or standard deviation if each measurement was repeated thrice or more). The revised data set is shown below

731$\pm$0.75, 772$\pm$2, 771$\pm$1.50, 681$\pm$1.75, 722$\pm$0.35, 688$\pm$0.25, 653$\pm$2.75, 757$\pm$1.10, 733$\pm$1.20, 742$\pm$0.90, 739$\pm$0.85, 780$\pm$0.60, 709$\pm$0.55, 676$\pm$0.20, 760$\pm$0.32, 748$\pm$0.27, 672$\pm$1.32, 687$\pm$2.31, 766$\pm$1.87, 645$\pm$1.90, 678$\pm$1.33, 748$\pm$1.29, 689$\pm$1.26, 810$\pm$1.37, 805$\pm$2.65, 778$\pm$3.05, 764$\pm$1.58, 753$\pm$1.61, 709$\pm$0.13, 675$\pm$1.21, 698$\pm$1.22, 770$\pm$1.30, 754$\pm$1.99, 830$\pm$0.77, 725$\pm$0.75, 710$\pm$0.81, 738$\pm$0.90, 638$\pm$2.1, 787$\pm$1.45, 712$\pm$0.38

My question is: Whether any statistics test can be used to check the hypothesis that the data (new data with uncertainty) is normally distributed?

Comment: "$\chi^2$ for a set of data" is not well defined.  In this context it could reflect a mean of squares of standardized values, or the chi-squared statistic for a table of values relative to predefined data intervals ("bins"), or even twice a difference of log likelihoods.  Please, then, edit your post so that it (a) explains what you mean by "$\chi^2$" and (b) tells us clearly what your statistical objective is.  (Computing a statistic rarely is an objective in its own right.)

Comment: I have accordingly edited the question.

Comment: Thank you.  You don't seem to have reproduced the entire question.  For instance, what are the bins?  Do you want to answer the question about whether the new data are normally distributed or the question about how to evaluate a chi-squared statistic or the implicit question about how to find a p-value for it?

Comment: The $\textit{bins}$ are same as that chosen by John Taylor. I want to know whether $\chi^2$ remains same as before irrespective of whether any standard deviation is associated with the data or the problem has to be handled differently.

Comment: Although the $\chi^2$ *statistic* obviously remains the same (because the numbers are the same), there is an issue of what the associated p-value should be.  The problem is rather opaque and Procrustean, though, because better methods than creating a variant of a $\chi^2$ test might occur to many people and the assumptions Taylor is making are not apparent.  Since you say this is a "solved problem," where are you looking for clarification?

Comment: The solution refers to the first part of the problem definition that I have already stated i.e .when there is no standard deviation. I have understood the solution provided by Taylor. I have modified the problem by associating some standard deviation to the data sets. I wish to solve the revised problem i.e apply $\chi^2$ distribution to check whether the new data sets (with standard deviation) are normally distributed. I wish to seek clarification on whether the distribution tests and steps therein are same irrespective of whether there is any associated standard deviation to the data sets.

Comment: Then you might consider reframing your question so that it elicits more useful responses: namely, without limiting the possible approaches to a $\chi^2$ test, you could ask how one might go about assessing Normality in the presence of measurement error with known variances.